# T-test with replicate measurements, how to quantify error in the measurements?

Tags: anova, t-test, error-propagation

I want to compare two tools, A and B.

I use tool A to measure 10 very different objects, making 5 repeated measurements for each object so I can record an accurate value.

I also do this with tool B.

Now I have some options:

1. Average each 5 replicate measurements and do a single paired t-test. But there must be some error in each measurement set (5 replicate), so how do I account for this error?
2. Do a separate t-test for each object. Let's say I can only reject the null hypothesis for some objects but not others. (And I don't know what aspect of the specific object affects the result.) How would I aggregate the result to get an overall comparison of A vs B?
3. Do an ANOVA test. But in this case I only care about two categories, I don't know if ANOVA is appropriate.

Comment: Selection of an appropriate procedure depends in part on what you expect of the measurement dispersions: should they be approximately the same for every object?  Or, perhaps, would you expect them to be proportional to each object's true value?

Comment: I expect the mean of the 5 replicates is very different for each object. 

Which procedure is then suitable for each case? a) the distribution of the 5 replicates is very similar, just around a different mean for each object, b) the distribution of the 5 replicates is different for each object due to random noise?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to perform a gage R&R study.  I suggest searching on that topic.